# Azure B2C ROPC alternative

Tags: android, ios, azure-ad-b2c

At the moment we use the [Azure B2C ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow to authenticate users in our native apps (iOs and Android). Because of security considerations and allowing the usage of multifactor authentication\single sign-on we would like to get rid of this flow. But when we submitted our app for approval it was rejected by Apple, because they want that the users stays inside the app when authenticating or subscribing. So we had to put back the ROPC flow. Anybody has an idea how we can provide an in app experience for subscribing and signing in, but without having to use the ROPC flows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [User Flows or Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy) (excluding ROPC flows) within an embedded webview will get approved. The MSAL library does this by default, sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-ios-app).

Comment: @jas-suri-msft any idea about a unity asset that supports this? Our Unity project creates multiple deployments both for iOs and Android?

Comment: possible https://uniwebview.com ?