# How to sign in using email and password to a Azure AD B2C app using HTTP REST?

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an API that signs in with **Azure AD B2C**. I need to test it using Postman, without opening a browser window. *I need the response to contain a JWT token, because in another flow of my API, users are going to use this token*. I cant use the SDK or libraries.

1. How do I set up the app correctly?
2. Do I need to set up any flows? If so, how should I set it up?
3. What should be the body of the request in postman? Which endpoint should I use?

I've done the setup with Azure AD (not B2C) and it worked for me, but I think it's because the configurations were very general and forgiving.

Comment: Which API you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: If you want to sign into the application without opening the browser then, you have to make use of ROPC flow.

- But as per Microsoft, ROPC flow isn't recommended due to security reasons.
- You can make use of Authorization code flow or PKCE or OBO flow, but it requires browser authentication.

Create an **Azure AD B2C application**:

[image]

Set **Allow public client flows as YES** and **enable the implicit flow**:

[image]

Now, create a resource owner user flow:

[image]

To generate the tokens, I used the below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPCflow/oauth2/v2.0/token

username:admin@b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com
password:***
grant_type:password
scope:openid ApplicationID offline_access
client_id:ClientID
```

[image]

**References:**

[Set up a resource owner password credentials flow - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow)

[android - Azure B2C ROPC alternative - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453605/azure-b2c-ropc-alternative) by Jas Suri - MSFT